# How to sum clients, group them by gender and then by month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in Pandas, which contains info about my clients and the month they bought something in my website:

```
id | Month| Gender
01 | 01 | M
02 | 01 | F
03 | 02 | F
04 | 02 | F
```

I need to know how many men and women bought something each month. In other words, i need to turn my original dataframe into this:

```
Month| Male| Female
01 | 100 |300
02 | 120 |500
03 | 170 |900
04 | 200 |1000
05 | 150 |800
```

How could I do that? I've tried a few different ways and none of them seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: where do the 100, 120, 300, 500, come from? Are those counting of rows? for when  Gender = M or Gender = F?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that more clear. Yes, the 100, 120, 300 and 500 are the counting of rows, where M is male and F is Female. The original dataframe has thousands of rows, not just 4 as I specified up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pivot_table` should work here:

```
df.assign(count=1).pivot_table(index='Month', columns = 'Gender', values='count', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

output

```
      Gender    F   M
Month       
1               1   1
2               2   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be:

```
cats = ['M','F']

df['Gender'] = pd.Categorical(df['Gender'], categories=cats, ordered=True)

df = df.groupby(['Month', 'Gender']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

which gives:

```
Gender  M  F
Month       
1       1  1
2       0  2
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Month, Count((CASE Gender  WHEN Gender='M' THEN 1 ) ) AS 'Male', Count((CASE Gender WHEN Gender='To THEN 1)) AS 'Female'
FROM table
Order By Month

Comment: Sorry bud, but this you wrote is SQL, not python

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you include your code in your question, so people can better help you. I made a new DataFrame by counting rows that satisfy both gender and month. There's probably a more efficient method, but this is what I have

```
def count_gender_in_month(month: int, gender: str) -> int:
   """
   counts number of rows that have given month and gender
   """
   return len(df[(df['month']==month) & (df['gender']==gender)])

# originial data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'month' : [1,1,2,2],
                   'gender' : ['M', 'F', 'F', 'F']})

months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

#converted data
ans = pd.DataFrame({'month' : months,
                   'male' : map(lambda x: count_gender_in_month(x, 'M'), months),
                   'female' : map(lambda x: count_gender_in_month(x, 'F'), months)})
```

Comment: Hey man, I just want to let you know your solution worked perfectly! It's not the shortest, and that's why i'm not signing it as the answer, but it's fully functional! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'month' : ['01','01','01','01','02','02','02'],
                    'gender' : ['M', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F','F','M']})
```

and the data looks like

```
month   gender
0   01  M
1   01  M
2   01  F
3   01  M
4   02  F
5   02  F
6   02  M

df['male'] = np.where(df['gender']=='M',1,0)
df['female'] = np.where(df['gender']=='F',1,0)
out  = df.pivot_table(index=['month'], values=['male','female'],aggfunc=sum,fill_value=0)
```

will give you

```
    female  male
month       
01  1       3
02  2       1
```